# Replace HDD Cage with another one

Tags: rack, rackmount

I have a HP Rackmountable 2U Server (HP ProLiant SE326M1). This Server has a P410i Raid Card with a hdd cage for 25x 2.5" SAS HDDs. Since 2.5" SAS HDDs are pretty expansive, I want to replace the cage with a cage for 3.5" HDDs. I tried searching on google and ebay for another cage, but didn't find any for rack servers. Is there a easy way to replace them and find another one or do I need to buy another server?

By Server Cage i mean the whole front where you can insert the HDDs:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2v07s.png)
Thank you for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a server, not a TARDIS that is bigger on the inside, you naturally can't replace the 2.5" drive carriers with bigger ones. How do you think this should work?

Note: If you have 3.5" drive bays in a server, you usually can get carriers that can take 2.5" disks, but not the other way around. Also, depending on the vendor, there might exist external disk enclosures for other drive types. Contact an HP sales representative.

Comment: I don't mean the small cages to make your hdd hot-swapable, but the whole cage where they go in. (added a picture to the question). And I know there wont be fitting 25 3.5" hdds in it, but at least 10 should be doable

Comment: That is the server case. Again: Contact your HP sales representative to find out if a compatible model with 3.5" drive bays exists and if you can buy an empty enclosure for this. If possible, you will find that you can just buy the more expensive disks and end up at roughly the same price point ...

Comment: Most of HPE servers have replaceable drive cages, so you could, for example, replace a 25 SFF drive cage with an 8 LFF cage.  Supposedly, the  SE326M1 is basically a renumbered DL180G6.  If this is actually true, a 506924-B21 should do the job.  The question is, how much time and money do you want to put into a 2009 vintage server?  Might be more cost effective to just replace the whole server.